# Whether is my conclusion about euler gamma function correct? is it new conclusion $\Gamma (0)=i\pi$?

Tags: gamma-function

I know that:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}\,dx=1$$

On the other hand
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{ dx}{({x^2+1^2)}^{3/2}}=\frac{(-1)^{3/2-1}\pi \Gamma (1/2)}{2\sin(\pi/2)(3/2-1)!\Gamma(1/2-3/2+1)}, \quad  0<3$$

This form of the equation is:

$$\frac{i\pi \sqrt \pi}{2\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}\Gamma[0]}=1$$

Which implies that:
$$\frac {i\pi}{\Gamma(0)}=1$$

in another word! Euler gamma function over zero is imaginary number times by pi number:
$i\pi=\Gamma(0)$ which is a transcendental number.

Whether is my conclusion about Euler Gamma function correct? is it new conclusion?

---

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^m \, dx}{({x^n+a^n)}^r}=\frac{(-1)^{r-1}\pi a^{m+1-nr}\Gamma [(m+1)/n]}{n\sin[\pi (m+1)/n](r-1)!\Gamma[((m+1)/n)-r+1]}, \quad  0<m+1<nr$$

set $m=0$, $a=1$, $n=2$ and $r=3/2$

Comment: $\Gamma(0) = \tilde{\infty}$.

Comment: You must have made a mistake somewhere since the Gamma function "blows up" at the origin.

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff maybe this point that in terms of the Gamma Function is only valid for integer values

Comment: $(3/2-1)!$ is not defined.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the formula for this integral (from your other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297437/gamma-frac-m1n-r1-while-it-could-be-gamma-frac-m1n-r)):

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^m \, dx}{({x^n+a^n)}^r}=\frac{(-1)^{r-1}\pi a^{m+1-nr}\Gamma [(m+1)/n]}{n\sin[\pi (m+1)/n](r-1)!\Gamma[(m+1)/n-r+1]}, \quad  0<m+1<nr$$

In terms of the Gamma Function is only valid for integer values of $r$ (GEdgar points out the same thing in the comments).

Your conclusion is obviously contradictory anyway, $\Gamma(0) = \tilde{\infty} \neq i\pi$.

Comment: What is infinity with a tilde over it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Complex infinity (infinity in the complex plane with an undefined argument). I get my notation from [Wolfram Functions Site](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Gamma/03/02/).

Comment: Thanks. Never saw it before.